# Insert without duplicates MS Access using ASP.net (VB.net)

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access, ado.net, duplicates

I am building an e-commerce website as a school project. How can I make sure that I won't have duplicate users since this is the page where they have to fill in their user details.

[image: Sell article page]

This is the code I am using right now and the ExecuteNonquery doesn't work. It doesn't give any errors, it just skips it.

```
Protected Sub bntVerzenden_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bntVerzenden.Click

    Dim sqlCommand As String
    Dim intGebruikersID, intRubriekID As Integer
    Dim VerkopenConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim VerkopenCommArtikel, VerkopenCommGebruiker, GebruikersIDComm, RubriekIDComm, EmailComm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand



    VerkopenConn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.SvShopConnection
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Connection = VerkopenConn
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Connection = VerkopenConn
    GebruikersIDComm.Connection = VerkopenConn
    RubriekIDComm.Connection = VerkopenConn
    EmailComm.Connection = VerkopenConn


    'Email Controleren
    sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblGebruiker WHERE GebruikersEmail = '" & txtEmail.Text & "'"

    EmailComm.CommandText = sqlCommand
    If VerkopenConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then VerkopenConn.Open()

    If EmailComm.ExecuteNonQuery = 0 Then


        'Gebruiker gegevens aan de database toevoegen
        VerkopenCommGebruiker.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblGebruiker (GebruikersNaam, GebruikersVoornaam, GebruikersEmail, GebruikersGSM) VALUES (@GebruikersNaam, @GebruikersVoornaam, @GebruikersEmail, @GebruikersGSM)"

        VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersNaam", txtNaam.Text)
        VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersVoornaam", txtVNaam.Text)
        VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersEmail", txtEmail.Text)
        VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersGSM", txtGsm.Text)



        VerkopenCommGebruiker.ExecuteNonQuery()


        'GebruikersID uit de database halen
        GebruikersIDComm.CommandText = "SELECT tblGebruiker.GebruikersID FROM tblGebruiker WHERE tblGebruiker.GebruikersNaam = @Naam AND tblGebruiker.GebruikersVoornaam = @VNaam;"

        GebruikersIDComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", txtNaam.Text)
        GebruikersIDComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VNaam", txtVNaam.Text)

        intGebruikersID = Integer.Parse(GebruikersIDComm.ExecuteScalar)

        'RubriekID uit de database halen
        RubriekIDComm.CommandText = "SELECT tblRubriek.RubriekID FROM tblRubriek WHERE tblRubriek.RubriekNaam = @RubriekNaam"

        RubriekIDComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RubriekNaam", lstRubriek.SelectedItem.ToString)
        intRubriekID = Integer.Parse(RubriekIDComm.ExecuteScalar)

        'Artikel gegevens aan de database toevoegen
        VerkopenCommArtikel.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblArtikel (ArtikelBeschrijving, ArtikelPrijs, RubriekID, ArtikelAankoopdatum, ArtikelTekoopgezet, ArtikelBeschikbaar, GebruikersID) VALUES ( @ArtikelBeschrijving, @ArtikelPrijs, @RubriekID, @ArtikelAankoopdatum, @ArtikelTekoopgezet, @ArtikelBeschikbaar, @GebruikersID)"

        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelBeschrijving", txtArtikelBeschrijving.Text)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelPrijs", txtArtikelPrijs.Text)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RubriekID", intRubriekID)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelAankoopdatum", CalAankoop.SelectedDate)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelTekoopgezet", calVerkoop.SelectedDate)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelBeschikbaar", True)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersID", intGebruikersID)

        VerkopenCommArtikel.ExecuteNonQuery()



        VerkopenConn.Close()

    Else




        'GebruikersID uit de database halen
        GebruikersIDComm.CommandText = "SELECT tblGebruiker.GebruikersID FROM tblGebruiker WHERE tblGebruiker.GebruikersNaam = @Naam AND tblGebruiker.GebruikersVoornaam = @VNaam;"

        GebruikersIDComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", txtNaam.Text)
        GebruikersIDComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VNaam", txtVNaam.Text)

        intGebruikersID = Integer.Parse(GebruikersIDComm.ExecuteScalar)

        'RubriekID uit de database halen
        RubriekIDComm.CommandText = "SELECT tblRubriek.RubriekID FROM tblRubriek WHERE tblRubriek.RubriekNaam = @RubriekNaam"

        RubriekIDComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RubriekNaam", lstRubriek.SelectedItem.ToString)
        intRubriekID = Integer.Parse(RubriekIDComm.ExecuteScalar)

        'Artikel gegevens aan de database toevoegen
        VerkopenCommArtikel.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblArtikel (ArtikelBeschrijving, ArtikelPrijs, RubriekID, ArtikelAankoopdatum, ArtikelTekoopgezet, ArtikelBeschikbaar, GebruikersID) VALUES ( @ArtikelBeschrijving, @ArtikelPrijs, @RubriekID, @ArtikelAankoopdatum, @ArtikelTekoopgezet, @ArtikelBeschikbaar, @GebruikersID)"

        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelBeschrijving", txtArtikelBeschrijving.Text)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelPrijs", txtArtikelPrijs.Text)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RubriekID", intRubriekID)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelAankoopdatum", CalAankoop.SelectedDate)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelTekoopgezet", calVerkoop.SelectedDate)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelBeschikbaar", True)
        VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersID", intGebruikersID)

        VerkopenCommArtikel.ExecuteNonQuery()



        VerkopenConn.Close()

    End If



    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""Jouw artikel staat nu te koop"")</SCRIPT>")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should hace some id field, like email or full name. You could create a unique index on this columna and catch the exception on insert. Or fire a first query to verify if the user is already added.

Comment: I have a UserID as PK that generates automatically when a user gets added to the table

Comment: If the PK is an autogenerated int, then it doesn't fit your needs. You need a natural PK, like email, ssn or similar to verify if the user already exists

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the emailid that user provide is already exist in your database or not.Try this code:-

```
 SqlConnection Conn=new SqlConnection(your_connectionstring);
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from tblGebruiker where GebruikersEmail='" + emailid + "'", Conn);
 DataTable dtl = new DataTable();
 SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
 sqlDA.Fill(dtl);


if (dtl.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('User already registered')</script>");
}
else
{
VerkopenCommGebruiker.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblGebruiker (GebruikersNaam, GebruikersVoornaam, GebruikersEmail, GebruikersGSM) VALUES (@GebruikersNaam, @GebruikersVoornaam, @GebruikersEmail, @GebruikersGSM)"

    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersNaam", txtNaam.Text)
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersVoornaam", txtVNaam.Text)
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersEmail", txtEmail.Text)
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersGSM", txtGsm.Text)

    If VerkopenConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then VerkopenConn.Open()
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

Comment: "select * from tblGebruiker where GebruikersEmail='" + emailid + "'"; NO. Don't use direct user input to create dynamic sql queries, this code is asking for an SQL Injection. Instead, use SqlCommand and SqlParameter class.

Comment: @Oscar what would you suggest than? I don't really understand what you mean with that.

Comment: @R C I can't seem to do this line: `SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)`

Comment: @ThimoDemey i have edited the answer. have u tried that??

Comment: @RC I've tried something else as you can see in the edited code.